Multiple manualChunks Vite
I am not familiar with Vite and I can't seem to find an answer to my problem.
I know this is far from correct, my project is complete and running fine.
Now my goal is that I want to have 2 files for this project.
If id is under 'src/components/InputTracker.tsx' it will return/create a file for this (autocomplete).
If id is 'src' then it will return main which should also include 'src/components/InputTracker.tsx'
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import cssInjectedByJsPlugin from 'vite-plugin-css-injected-by-js';

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/setupTests.ts',
    globals: true,
    css: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': '/src'
    }
  },
  plugins: [react(), cssInjectedByJsPlugin()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('src')) {
            return 'main'
          }
        },
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('src/App.tsx')) {
            return 'autocomplete'
          }
        },
        chunkFileNames: '[name]-[hash].js'
      }
    }
  }
});

my problem with putting them under the single manualChunks, 'main' file seem to skip InputTracker and also since it only returns 1 value. I have also already tried using array and pushing them but it doesn't seem to work correctly

        manualChunks(id) {
          const chunks = [];
          if (id.includes('src')) {
            chunks.push('autocomplete');
          }
          if (id.includes('src/App.tsx')) {
            chunks.push('main');
          }
          return chunks.length > 0 ? chunks.join('-') : undefined;
        },
        chunkFileNames: '[name]-[hash].js'

